# android call log ContentResolver

Tags: android

I am trying to retrieve call log in android using getContentResolver().

I am getting the following error

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getContentResolver() from the type ContextWrapper
```

Can you please explain me on this.I am just starting up with android and java.

```
public static void GetCalls() {
    String[] CallDetails =  {
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls._ID,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE,
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
    };
    Cursor cursor;

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.CONTENT_URI, CallDetails, null, null,null);             
}
```

Comment: Remove Static keyword from method

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Make your method non-static, this way you will be able to use `getContentResolver()`
2. Pass a `context` item to your method and then use `context.getContentResolver()`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String getCallDetails(Context context) {

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
    int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);       
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = cursor.getString(number);
        String callType = cursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = cursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = cursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            dir = "OUTGOING";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            dir = "INCOMING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            dir = "MISSED";
            break;
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}``

Don't forget to add permission-
<android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>

Hope this helps..
```